# How to do Pixel collision detected in cocos2d in android

Tags: cocos2d-android

I am new to cocos2d and I am using cocos2d lib in eclipse in java to make a game.I want to do a pixel collision.My game is a 2d game,a ball running in a maze, and i want to detect the collision between the maze wall and the ball, i cant use getpixel in CCSprite. So how can i do it?
CCSprite.getpixel doesn't exsist. I only can do checking bounding box collision between two sprite..but don't know how to do pixel compare pixel point by point..

```
 public boolean isCollisionDetected(CCSprite maze,CCSprite ball)
{


    CGRect bounds1 = maze.getBoundingBox();
    CGRect bounds2 = ball.getBoundingBox();


     if( CGRect.intersects(bounds1, bounds2) ){
/* i want to do pixel detection in here,actually i want to do something like this
            for (int i = collisionBounds.left; i < collisionBounds.right; i++) {
                for (int j = collisionBounds.top; j < collisionBounds.bottom; j++) {
                    int sprite1Pixel = getBitmapPixel(sprite1, i, j);
                    int sprite2Pixel = getBitmapPixel(sprite2, i, j); 
                    if( isFilled(sprite1Pixel) && isFilled(sprite2Pixel)) {
                        return true;
                    }*/


         return true;

     }
        return false;
```

}

but Cocos2d, sprite doesn't support this kind of method.

Comment: can you add a rough image of , what exactly you want

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to collision detection for a circle you have to compare the radius of the circle with the distance from the center of the circle to the other object. If the radius of the circle is equal to or less than the distance between the center of the circle and the object, there is a collision.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Its for circle , but what if for example take a man or his body, what will you do that time?